# url-http unable to connect to api - gnutls error

Tags: gnutls

I am using `restclient-mode` and trying to POST JSON to an API I'm writing. Making curl requests works fine but I'm getting these errors from restclient.el:

My restclient-mode request looks like this:

```
POST https://www.example.com/
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "email": "bitops@example.com",
  "password": "secretP@55word"
}
```

I see this output in the **Messages** buffer:

```
Contacting host: **API URL**:443
Opening TLS connection to `**API URL**'...
Opening TLS connection with `gnutls-cli --insecure -p 443 **API URL**'...failed
Opening TLS connection with `gnutls-cli --insecure -p 443 **API URL** --protocols ssl3'...failed
Opening TLS connection with `openssl s_client -connect **API URL**:443 -no_ssl2 -ign_eof'...failed
Opening TLS connection to `**API URL**'...failed
url-http: Could not create connection to **API URL**:443
```

My gnutls-cli info:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/gnutls-cli --version
gnutls-cli 3.3.9
```

Comment: Just made a [successful](http://i325.photobucket.com/albums/k362/LeMeteore/Capture%20deacutecran%20-%2013042015%20-%20232632_zpsri7pe5po.png) request, same url, same datas. I'm using gnutls-cli (GnuTLS) 2.12.20 Packaged by Debian (2.12.20-8+deb7u3)

Comment: @Nsukami_ it works for me too in other scenarios. I just don't know how to proceed further or get better debug information.

Comment: So, can we know more about your environment/setup? Do you have a proxy? Do you wear google glasses when the error occurs? etc ...

Comment: @Nsukami_ I use a pretty vanilla Emacs install. Nothing special. Emacs 24.4, OS X, installed from Emacs for Mac OSX. No proxy and I'm able to post to other sites just fine.